# Contact Forms + PHP + Validation

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm trying to get my simple contact form to be functional. I want this form to either email me or record the contact data somewhere. I'm just now starting to learn PHP and Javascript -- so my knowledge is extremely limited.

The validation seems to be working (it will alert you if you don't put in a valid email, for example) -- but the form itself isn't being submitted anywhere.

When you enter information and click submit you'll get an  ERROR 404 - Not Found  (Then it references contact.php -- the php file I'm using) How can I start to troubleshoot this? Furthermore, if you have a clear, simple resource for learning about PHP and forms then I'd be more than happy to study more. I've searched (for a few hours) for decent tutorials but most don't provide clear explanations -- and just encourage you to copy and paste code.

```
<form role="form" id="contactform" form action="contact.php" method="post">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                    <input type="subject" class="form-control" id="subject">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
                  <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">Message Submitted!</div>
                </form>
```

---PHP---

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

$EmailTo = "william@whatsauce.com";
$Subject = "New Message Received";

// prepare email body text
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .="Subject: ";
$Body .= $subject;
$Body .= "\n";

$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);

// redirect to success page
if ($success){
   echo "success";
}else{
    echo "invalid";
}

?>
```

Comment: Provide any relevant code and error messages. Please don't expect us to go to some random website to try and diagnose issues.

Comment: I just don't know what code to include. The HTML, JS, and PHP??

Comment: We don't know? Narrow down the issue and that'll answer what code to provide. Do some debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I already mentioned that I'm a complete newbie. I'm willing to put in the work if you just point me in the right direction.

Comment: What is the name of the PHP file? Also, is it in the same directory as the file with your form?

Comment: contact.php  --> Yeah, it's in the same directory for now.

Comment: No idea then. Since you're getting a 404, the web server doesn't believe that is the case.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll double check and make sure everything is where it should be. I'll check that tonight when I get home. I appreciate the prompt replies!

Answer (score 0):

Use a name attribute in your input fields. Only then you will be able to capture them values in your $_POST as a valid index, not through ids.